stuck at "Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers"
i am using ros2 humble, gazebo classic
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.003842791] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.005479106] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.005604864] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.006130328] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/ros2/ros2_robots/Kelvin6k/install/kelvin6k_gazebo/share/kelvin6k_gazebo/config/kelvin6k_controllers.yaml
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.008161278] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.010749810] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1724932460.021660615] [gazebo_ros2_control]: The position_proportional_gain parameter was not defined, defaulting to: 0.1
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.022417482] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_link_to_X_axis_joint
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.022577912] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.022614558] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.022932938] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.022956709] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023475859] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: X_axis_to_Y_axis_joint
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023510101] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023525394] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023649327] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023659651] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023742158] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: Y_axis_to_Z_axis_joint
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023757693] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023764331] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023772579] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.023782010] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.024036437] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'RobotSystem' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.024588564] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'RobotSystem'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.024703940] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'RobotSystem' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.024709728] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'RobotSystem'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.024714954] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'RobotSystem' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.024718504] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'RobotSystem'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.025010777] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.032977106] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1724932460.033598881] [gazebo_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.01 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.034276503] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded gazebo_ros2_control.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.039213753] [gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher]: Going to publish joint [base_link_to_X_axis_joint]
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.039233465] [gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher]: Going to publish joint [X_axis_to_Y_axis_joint]
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1724932460.039239978] [gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher]: Going to publish joint [Y_axis_to_Z_axis_joint]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 62872]
[spawner-4] [WARN] [1724932469.199083933] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1724932469.200182955] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawner-1] [WARN] [1724932469.201438629] [spawner_arm_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-1] [INFO] [1724932469.202139998] [spawner_arm_controller]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawner-1] [WARN] [1724932479.217963396] [spawner_arm_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-1] [INFO] [1724932479.218767280] [spawner_arm_controller]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawner-4] [WARN] [1724932479.220188922] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1724932479.221517540] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawner-1] [WARN] [1724932489.234461565] [spawner_arm_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-1] [INFO] [1724932489.235190458] [spawner_arm_controller]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...

my launch file
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import AppendEnvironmentVariable, DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import Command, PathJoinSubstitution, LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

def generate_launch_description():

  # Constants for paths to different files and folders
  package_name_description = 'kelvin6k_description'
  package_name_gazebo = 'kelvin6k_gazebo'

  default_robot_name = 'kelvin6k'
  gazebo_launch_file_path = 'launch'
  gazebo_models_path = 'models'
  rviz_config_file_path = 'rviz/kelvin6k_view_description.rviz'
  urdf_file_path = 'urdf/ros2_control/kelvin6k.urdf.xacro'
  world_file_path = 'worlds/empty.world' 

  # Set the path to different files and folders.  
  pkg_gazebo_ros = FindPackageShare(package='gazebo_ros').find('gazebo_ros')  
  pkg_share_description = FindPackageShare(package=package_name_description).find(package_name_description)
  pkg_share_gazebo = FindPackageShare(package=package_name_gazebo).find(package_name_gazebo)

  default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_description, rviz_config_file_path)  
  default_urdf_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_gazebo, urdf_file_path)
  gazebo_launch_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_gazebo, gazebo_launch_file_path)   
  gazebo_models_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_gazebo, gazebo_models_path)
  world_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_gazebo, world_file_path)
  
  # Launch configuration variables specific to simulation
  headless = LaunchConfiguration('headless')
  robot_name = LaunchConfiguration('robot_name')
  rviz_config_file = LaunchConfiguration('rviz_config_file')
  urdf_model = LaunchConfiguration('urdf_model')
  use_robot_state_pub = LaunchConfiguration('use_robot_state_pub')
  use_rviz = LaunchConfiguration('use_rviz')
  use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
  use_simulator = LaunchConfiguration('use_simulator')
  world = LaunchConfiguration('world')
  
  # Set the default pose
  x = LaunchConfiguration('x')
  y = LaunchConfiguration('y')
  z = LaunchConfiguration('z')
  roll = LaunchConfiguration('roll')
  pitch = LaunchConfiguration('pitch')
  yaw = LaunchConfiguration('yaw')
  
  # Declare the launch arguments  
  declare_robot_name_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='robot_name',
    default_value=default_robot_name,
    description='The name for the robot')

  declare_rviz_config_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='rviz_config_file',
    default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
    description='Full path to the RVIZ config file to use')

  declare_simulator_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='headless',
    default_value='False',
    description='Display the Gazebo GUI if False, otherwise run in headless mode')

  declare_urdf_model_path_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='urdf_model', 
    default_value=default_urdf_model_path, 
    description='Absolute path to robot urdf file')
    
  declare_use_robot_state_pub_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_robot_state_pub',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether to start the robot state publisher')

  declare_use_rviz_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_rviz',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether to start RVIZ')
    
  declare_use_sim_time_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_sim_time',
    default_value='true',
    description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true')

  declare_use_simulator_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_simulator',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether to start Gazebo')

  declare_world_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='world',
    default_value=world_path,
    description='Full path to the world model file to load')

  declare_x_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='x',
    default_value='0.0',
    description='x component of initial position, meters')

  declare_y_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='y',
    default_value='0.0',
    description='y component of initial position, meters')
    
  declare_z_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='z',
    default_value='0.05', # 0.05 for house_classic.world and empty_classic.world, 0.2 for small_warehouse_classic.world
    description='z component of initial position, meters')
    
  declare_roll_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='roll',
    default_value='0.0',
    description='roll angle of initial orientation, radians')

  declare_pitch_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='pitch',
    default_value='0.0',
    description='pitch angle of initial orientation, radians')

  declare_yaw_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='yaw',
    default_value='0.0',
    description='yaw angle of initial orientation, radians')
    
  # Specify the actions

  set_env_vars_resources = AppendEnvironmentVariable(
    'GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH',
    gazebo_models_path)
  
  # Launch arm controller
  start_arm_controller_cmd = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=[
      "arm_controller",
      "--controller-manager",
      "/controller_manager"
    ]
  )  

  """   robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("kelvin6k_gazebo"),
            "config",
            "kelvin6k_controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )

  control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[default_urdf_model_path,robot_controllers],
        output="both",
    ) """
  # Start Gazebo server
  start_gazebo_server_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
      os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzserver.launch.py')),
    condition=IfCondition(use_simulator),
    launch_arguments={'world': world}.items())

  # Start Gazebo client    
  start_gazebo_client_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
      os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzclient.launch.py')),
    condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression([use_simulator, ' and not ', headless])))

  # Launch joint state broadcaster
  start_joint_state_broadcaster_cmd = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=[
      "joint_state_broadcaster",
      "--controller-manager",
      "/controller_manager"
    ]
  )  
  
  # Subscribe to the joint states of the robot, and publish the 3D pose of each link.
  robot_description_content = ParameterValue(Command(['xacro ', urdf_model]), value_type=None)
  start_robot_state_publisher_cmd = Node(
    condition=IfCondition(use_robot_state_pub),
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    name='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[{
      'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 
      'robot_description': robot_description_content}])

  # Launch RViz
  start_rviz_cmd = Node(
    condition=IfCondition(use_rviz),
    package='rviz2',
    executable='rviz2',
    name='rviz2',
    output='screen',
    arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file])  
    
  # Spawn the robot
  start_gazebo_ros_spawner_cmd = Node(
    package='gazebo_ros',
    executable='spawn_entity.py',
    arguments=[
      '-entity', robot_name,
      '-topic', "robot_description", 
      '-x', x,
      '-y', y,
      '-z', z,
      '-R', roll,
      '-P', pitch,
      '-Y', yaw
      ],
    output='screen')  
  
  # Create the launch description and populate
  ld = LaunchDescription()

  # Declare the launch options
  ld.add_action(declare_robot_name_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_rviz_config_file_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_simulator_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_urdf_model_path_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_use_robot_state_pub_cmd)  
  ld.add_action(declare_use_rviz_cmd) 
  ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_use_simulator_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_world_cmd)

  ld.add_action(declare_x_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_y_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_z_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_roll_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_pitch_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_yaw_cmd)  

  # Add any actions
  ld.add_action(set_env_vars_resources)
  ld.add_action(start_arm_controller_cmd) 
  ld.add_action(start_gazebo_server_cmd)
  ld.add_action(start_gazebo_client_cmd)
  #ld.add_action(control_node)

  ld.add_action(start_joint_state_broadcaster_cmd)
  ld.add_action(start_robot_state_publisher_cmd)
  ld.add_action(start_rviz_cmd)  
  ld.add_action(start_gazebo_ros_spawner_cmd)

  return ld

my controller file
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 

    arm_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
 
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
    joints:
      - base_link_to_X_axis_joint
      - X_axis_to_Y_axis_joint
      - Y_axis_to_Z_axis_joint

    command_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
  
    open_loop_control: false
 
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

    allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: true
 

i have installed controller_manager still not working
while running

ros2 control list_controllers
[INFO] [1724933618.480537987] [_ros2cli_65797]: waiting for service
/controller_manager/list_controllers to become available... [WARN]
[1724933628.502824242] [_ros2cli_65797]: Could not contact service
/controller_manager/list_controllers

topic list
ros2 topic list
/clock
/controller_manager/robot_description
/joint_states
/parameter_events
/performance_metrics
/robot_description
/rosout
/set_joint_trajectory
/tf
/tf_static


I have the exact same problem, and I am also on ROS Humble, Ubuntu 22.04. Trying to launch gazebo simulation for a UR robot, using ur_simulation_gz package from Universal_Robots_ROS2_GZ_Simulation, and I got the same error message. However, I didn't find this problem with the Example 9: Simulation with RRBot example from ros2_control_demos. Did you try with this specific example ? If it is working this might be an issue with

I have the exact same problem, and I am also on ROS Humble, Ubuntu 22.04.
Trying to launch gazebo simulation for a UR robot, using ur_simulation_gz package from Universal_Robots_ROS2_GZ_Simulation, and I got the same error message.
However, I didn't find this problem with the Example 9: Simulation with RRBot example from ros2_control_demos. Did you try with this specific example ? If it is working this might be an issue with your launch file or controller file, maybe.

I tried to add a timeout to the controller_manager: --controller-manager-timeout 100 for example, to let the simulation start and then call the controller_manager, changed nothing for me, but you can give it a try.

